# Random timestamp within last 3 relative years

Tags: performance, datetime, random, go

I'm trying to generate a random time between now and 3 years ago. To my knowledge, Go doesn't have a `random(min,max)` feature in either `math/rand` or `crypto/rand` where `min > 0`. To naively combat that, I generate a slice containing every time stamp within the relative now and 3 years ago, and then select the index at random with `rand.Intn(len(timeRange))`, because I am guaranteed to get a random index between 0 and `len(timeRange)`. It works just fine, and I get a Unix time stamp sometime between now and 3 years ago. However, I want to generate just one timestamp, not ~94m of them and then randomly picking one...it's egregiously slow.

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "math/rand"
    "fmt"
)

func randomTimestamp() time.Time {
    now := time.Now().Unix()
    threeYearsAgo := int64(now - 94608000)
    timeRange := make([]int64,1)
    for i := threeYearsAgo; i < now; i++ {
        timeRange = append(timeRange, i)
    }
    randomTime := rand.Intn(len(timeRange))

    randomNow := time.Unix(timeRange[randomTime], 0)

    return randomNow
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 25; i++ {
        fmt.Println(randomTimestamp().Format(time.RFC3339))
    }
}
```

How can I optimise `randomTimestamp()` so it doesn't have to calculate every second over the last 3 years, but it randomly picks one between now and 3 years ago?

Comment: I don't know the in's and out's of your language, but from an abstract logic point of view, surely you can just select a random integer between 0 and 94608000, then subtract your integer from now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Darren H has said in the comments, just generate a random number between 0 and nanoseconds in three years, and subtract from `time.Now()`:

```
const threeYears = 3 * 365 * 24 * time.Hour

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    d := time.Duration(rand.Int63n(int64(threeYears)))
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Add(-d))
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer (bonus points for seeding the `rand` package properly). Small nit: the `int64` conversion is unnecessary due to the way [numerical constants work in Go](https://blog.golang.org/constants).

Comment: @Ted I'm afraid that's wrong. `time.Hour` is typed, so `threeYears` has the type `time.Duration`. You can try and remove the conversion yourself and get `cannot use threeYears (type time.Duration) as type int64 in argument to rand.Int63`.